# Вызов функции у аргумента, переданного в функцию как константная ссылка

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
struct point
{
public:
   point(double x, double y)
   {
      x_ = x;
      y_ = y;
   }

   const double get_x()
   {
      return x_;
   }

   const double get_y()
   {
      return y_;
   }

private:
   double x_, y_;
};

point point_to_vector(const point& begin, const point& end)
{
   return point(end.get_x() - begin.get_x(), end.get_y() - begin.get_y());
}
```

VS2010 ругается:

> error: the object has qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function

Объясните, что не так.

Comment: `const double` - это излишество, поскольку возвращение в случае примитивных типов происходит по значению. Неизлишним `const` будет в случае возвращении ссылки и, например, при создании шаблонных классов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
struct point
{
public:
    point(double x, double y)
    {
       x_ = x;
       y_ = y;
    }

    const double get_x() const
    {
       return x_;
    }

    const double get_y() const
    {
       return y_;
    }

    private:
       double x_, y_;
};
```

Константный this может быть передан только в те методы, которые имеют квалификатор const.

**Добавление.**

[Справка по квалификаторам типа](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B_%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0).

Comment: То есть "const double get_x()" - бред, или писать перед функциями "const" имеет какой-то смысл?

Comment: Нет, не бред, просто в обоих случаях const имеет различное значение; так, Ваш метод "const double get_x()" возвращает константу double; в то время как квалификатор метода влияет на квалификацию указателя this, передаваемого в метод. Вам нужен ликбез по cv-квалификаторам: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B_%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0